# Obtaining points from the dxf using dxfgrabber module python

Tags: python

In the below i got the circles and the lines that are in the given dxf. I want the points. I tried something that i didn't understand from the documentation of the dxfGrabber module. Can anyone help please.

```
import dxfgrabber
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
dxf=dxfgrabber.readfile("3.dxf")
#version=dxf.header["$ACADVER"]
output=[entity for entity in dxf.entities if entity.layer =='0']
q=[]
for line in output:
    q.append(line)
w=[]
i=0
l=[]
c=[]
lines = [entity for entity in output if entity.dxftype == 'LWPOLYLINE']

circles= [entity for entity in output if entity.dxftype == 'CIRCLE']

for line in lines:
    l.append(line)
for part in circles:
    c.append(part)
references = [entity for entity in dxf.entities if entity.dxftype == '             

test= dxf.blocks
points=[]
points=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Collect all center points of all circles:

   center_points = [entity.center for entity in output if entity.dxftype ==   'CIRCLE']

Result: center_points is a list of (x, y, z) tuples.

2. Collect vertices of all LWPOLYLINES:

   list_of_vertices = [entity.points for entity in output if entity.dxftype == 'LWPOLYLINE']

Result: list_of_vertices is a list of vertex lists and each vertex is a (x, y) tuple.

Comment: So i should test for every block type if the dxf has ellipse,Arc  and parabola! .Instead can i get all the points at a time?

Comment: dxf.entities contains all entities from model space. dxf.blocks contains all block definitions. Each block is a separated entity space which is placed in model space by the INSERT entity. If you collect entities from block definitions you just get the original position of the entities in the block entity space, not the position of the entities created by INSERT in the drawing model space.

Comment: In your example you just collect entities from layer '0', are you sure that your entities are on layer '0'? Replace 'output' by 'dxf.entities' to search the whole model space.

Comment: i did so . even now result remains same.

Comment: It seems there are no CIRCLE or LWPOLYLINE entities in model space.

Answer (score 0):

I added round numbers

```
import dxfgrabber
    
def round_vertices(vertices_list: list, ndigits: int):
            rounded_vertices = []
            for vertex in vertices_list:
                rounded_vertex = []
                for coordinate in vertex:
                    rounded_vertex.append(round(coordinate, ndigits))
                rounded_vertices.append(tuple(rounded_vertex))
            return rounded_vertices
    
dxf=dxfgrabber.readfile("3.dxf")
output=[entity for entity in dxf.entities if entity.layer =='0']
list_of_vertices = [round_vertices(entity.points, 7) for entity in output if entity.dxftype == 'LWPOLYLINE']
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain what your code does. It would help the community much more that way to learn from you!